# Editing object file on osx (cf objcopy)

Tags: macos, linker, ld, objcopy

How can I edit object files on osx?
For example, renaming or removing a symbol from an object file.
I've tried binutil's gobjcopy:

```
gobjcopy --strip-symbol some_symbol foo.o foo2.o
```

This seems to work but `ld` complains when linking foo2.o (it didn't complain with foo.o). This also happens in the simplest form (`gobjcopy foo.o foo2.o`).

```
/opt/local/bin/ranlib: file: mylib.a(foo2.o) malformed object (symbol 0 must not have NO_SECT for its n_sect field given its type (N_SECT))
```

Background: I'm trying to remove a duplicate symbol defined in 2 object files.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out objconv, it seems to do the job.